# JavaFX: Why is there no setItems() on some controls?

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, enums, fxml

I'm using `CheckComboBox` from ControlsFX, and since it doesn't have a method `setItems()`, I have to hard-code the values in the FXML:

```
<CheckComboBox fx:id="servicesComboBox" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
    <items>
        <Service fx:value="WATER"/>
        <Service fx:value="TRASH"/>
        <Service fx:value="STREET_LIGHTING"/>
        <Service fx:value="SEWER"/>
        <Service fx:value="PUBLIC_TRANSPORT"/>
        <Service fx:value="PIT"/>
        <Service fx:value="PIPE"/>
        <Service fx:value="INTERNET"/>
        <Service fx:value="ELECTRICITY"/>
        <Service fx:value="CABLE"/>
    </items>
</CheckComboBox>
```

where, `Service` is an Enum.

Why is there no `set*(ObservableList<T> value)` in CheckComboBox, SegmentedButton to name a few controls where as ListView, ComboBox and other JavaFX controls have them?

Comment: Just use `getItems().addAll()` ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha, right, didn't see that. thanks, could you add it as answer? just to accept it

Comment: Would you mind if I edit the question to be about "why `setItems()` is absent?" and add an answer which describes the reason?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha please, go ahead